# Difference between Objective and feval in xgboost

Tags: r, classification, xgboost, objective-function, evaluation-function

What is the difference between `objective` and `feval` in xgboost in R? I know this is something very fundamental but I am unable to exactly define them/ their purpose.

Also, what is a softmax objective, while doing multi class classification?

Answer (score 61):

**Objective**

`Objective` in `xgboost` is the [function](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md#learning-task-parameters) which the learning algorithm will try and optimize.  By definition, it must be able to create 1st (gradient) and 2nd (hessian) derivatives w.r.t. the predictions at a given  training round.

A custom `Objective` function example:[link](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/R-package/demo/custom_objective.R#L14)

```
# user define objective function, given prediction, return gradient and second order gradient
# this is loglikelihood loss
logregobj <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  preds <- 1/(1 + exp(-preds))
  grad <- preds - labels
  hess <- preds * (1 - preds)
  return(list(grad = grad, hess = hess))
}
```

**This is the critical function to training** and no `xgboost` model can be trained without defining one. `Objective` functions are directly used in splitting at each node in each tree.

**feval**

`feval` in  `xgboost` plays no role in directly optimizing or training your model.   You don't even need one to train. It doesn't impact splitting. All it does is score your model AFTER it has trained.  A look at a example of a custom `feval`

```
evalerror <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  err <- as.numeric(sum(labels != (preds > 0)))/length(labels)
  return(list(metric = "error", value = err))
}
```

Notice, it just returns a name(metric) and a score(value).   Typically the `feval` and `objective` could be the same, but maybe the scoring mechanism you want is a little different, or doesn't have derivatives.  For example, people use the logloss `objective` to train, but create an AUC `feval` to evaluate the model.

Furthermore you can use the `feval` to stop your model from training once it stops improving.  And you can use multiple `feval` functions to score your model in different ways and observe them all.

You do not need a `feval` function to train a model.  Only to evaluate it, and help it stop training early.

***Summary:***

`Objective` is the main workhorse.

`feval` is a helper to allow `xgboost` to do some cool things.

`softmax` is an `objective` function that is commonly used in multi-class classification.  It insures that all your predictions sum to one, and are scaled using the exponential function. [softmax](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-significance-of-the-softmax-function)